# Best AWS Service to Put PySpark / ML Code into Production

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon

I am very new to MLOps and seeking guidance on how to put a piece of ML python code into production on AWS.

Here are my requirements:

1. Model is run once a week
2. Pick up very large data files from S3
3. Models are stored in S3 and will need to be loaded from there as well
4. Data processing is done in PySpark
5. Processed data is then converted into Pandas for further processing before being fed into models
6. Models are typically SkLearn or XGBoost
7. Model results should be stored back in S3

Any idea of what service is best for this? Again, I have very limited experience outside of writing ML models in python, so anything that is simple where I am not managing or worrying about infrastructure is preferable. However, I will do what I must to put the code into production on AWS.